# Python opencv cv2.VideoCapture.read() getting stuck indefinitely after running the first time

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-streaming, streaming

I am using opencv on python and I'm facing an issue where the `cv2.VideoCapture.read()` function gets stuck. Here's some prototype code:

requirements.txt

```
opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.26
```

application.py

```
import cv2

def run_analysis(path_to_video):
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)

    while True:
         frame = vs.read()
         if frame is None:
             break
         do_stuff_with_frame(frame)

    vs.release()
```

This code works all the time on my mac. It works only the first time around when I deploy it as a Flask app to Elastic Beanstalk (runs on Red Hat Linux).
I've seen some stuff in github issues that might suggest that vs.release() fails to release the file pointer, or that there's a memory leak, but I'm not too well versed in these concepts.

Even if I can't get an answer for why, I'd be happy with a brute force way of making it work.

Comment: first you should try to reproduce the problem yourself, by mirroring the customer's environment. Afterward, identify the bug, where exactly it happens. If you can't mirror the enviroment, you should try to let your customer test for you, by giving him code where you replace the `do_stuff_with_frame(frame)` by a simple print (or similar) to make sure it is not a problem in your processing, but really with the file or the capturing functions. Or do you know already, that it freezes in the vs.release call?

Comment: It does not freeze on release. It freezes on subsequent calls of vs.read. Other sources have suggested that vs.release previously failed. The only way to reset it is by killing the flask app and restarting it.
Anyway I switched from Elastic Beanstalk to Heroku which uses ubuntu I believe. I don't have the issue anymore so I don't really need an answer.
(Will still honor the award for an answer which solves it though)

Answer (score 4):

You can add guards to ensure that the `cv2.VideoCapture()` handler object is valid with `isOpened()`. In addition, you can check the `status` return value from `read()` to ensure that the frame is valid. Also ensure that the path given to the handler is valid.

```
import cv2

def run_analysis(path_to_video):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error opening video")

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        status, frame = cap.read()
        if status:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            # do_stuff_with_frame(frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(25)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_analysis('video.mp4')
```

Comment: Thanks although I'm not sure how this solves my issue. I'm presuming it will just keep printing the error statement then. I suppose I can try it just to check if I have a misunderstanding of the problem.

Comment: Why would it  _"just keep printing the error statement "_? The only error to print on this code is file loading itself fails otherwise, if loaded okay, it will break the while loop at press of `q` on keyboard. In programming, a While-loop repeats infinitely until a stopping condition is met. Did pressing `q` give expected result of stopping (exiting) the While loop?

Comment: You're probably getting stuck indefinitely due to either a corrupted capture handler or invalid frame. With this proposed change, we add guards with every iteration of each frame to ensure that the capture object is valid in addition to checking that we have a valid frame. It will print the error only on the 1st iteration if the capture object is corrupted. Maybe your path to the video file is incorrect?

Comment: @VC.One I think maybe I didn't explain my question well enough. I know where it breaks and under what conditions. No further diagnosis is required. It freezes on vs.read() and that is all. If I run your code I presume I would just get the error message printed out. Then if I run it again, it will print it again.

Comment: @nathancy thanks. I know two things which suggest it's not to do with a corrupt frame. 1) it works the first time I run it. On the second time, I use the same video file. 2) it works every time on my Mac.

Comment: Anyway I sorted this all out by completely ditching Elastic Beanstalk and switching to Heroku. It uses Ubuntu I believe, so switching OS sorted the issue. I just don't know how to shut the question down, as technically I still don't have an answer which solves it

Comment: @AlexanderSoare interesting, so there was no error before switching OS? That's an anticlimactic solution, are you sure the problem will not appear again?

Comment: No error after switching OS. And I really doubt it will appear again. It was 100% consistent before and non-existent after.

Answer (score 2):

According to `openCV` [web site](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

> If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.

you could test to see if 'frame' is false after you test it for 'None'.
If in doubt, 'print(frame)'

Edit:
I just realized your skipping the most important step with opening a file.
Need to check if it opened with isOpened()

```
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
    if not vs.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open file: %s" % (path_to_video))
        return
    ........
```

Edit:
Try this code. By expanded the `vs.read()` it becomes a little more clear as to what it is returning.

```
import cv2
def do_stuff_with_frame(image):
    pass

def run_analysis(path_to_video):
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
    if not vs.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open file: %s" % (path_to_video))
        return

    while True:
        retval, image = vs.read()
        if not retval:
            print("Video file finished. Total Frames: %d" % (vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))
            break
        do_stuff_with_frame(image)

    vs.release()

# START OF PROGRAM
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_analysis("test.mov")
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the response. I don't think my problem is in the way I check if `frame is None`. The code actually gets stuck on the `frame = vs.read()` line and doesn't continue to the next line.

Comment: I also read that the `frame` object should not be altered, if your changing anything in it during `do_stuff_with_frame()` there is a clone function which will return a editable frame.

Comment: yeah, actually I do copy the frame each time but using list.copy() instead. maybe it's trying to switch to the inbuilt clone function

Comment: You could comment out your do_stuff method and see if the loop finished. That will narrow down the error

Comment: well the way I've done it is by inserting log statements in between each line (there are probably better ways but I don't know how to do debugging in production). The log statement after vs.read() never fires. Let me know if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. when you use `frame` you treat it as a list correct? [see the usage here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.VideoCapture.read) before using the `image` make sure `retval` is True. What does `print(frame)` output?

Comment: print frame outputs a multi-dimensional list. I will test some of these things and come back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Anything?? I have this same issue and been stuck on it for days

Comment: Are there any further information about this bug? Still having this issue based on OpencV 4.5.0. VideoCapture.isOpened() returns true.