# Process multiple files in a tensorflow session

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

```
func_name(loc, id , mn):    
    with detection_graph.as_default():
         with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
                #tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

                while cap.isOpened():
                    ret, image_np = cap.read()
                    print(ret)

                    if not ret:
                        break
                    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
                    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
                    # Extract image tensor
        sess.close()
```

I send a file using 
`func_name(location, id, model_name)` to the above normal object detection session code to process and then save and return, however after I try to send another file without exiting the program I get the first frame and then nothing happens i.e the processing doesn't happen like the first file for all the files after processing the first file.

How do I process multiple files without exiting the code and restarting?
I tried `initialize variables` and `sess.close()` but it still doesn't work.
Multiple files are uploaded using `flask`.

`UPDATE 1`

the `detect_func()` gets called from a different script from where it gets all the arguments it requires.

```
import numpy as np
import os

import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import cv2

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
# from models.research import *
#from models.research.object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from codes.models.research.object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from codes.models.research.object_detection.utils import label_map_util


#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Change only if you have more than one webcams

# What model to download.
# Models can bee found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

# Number of classes to detect
NUM_CLASSES = 90

# Download Model
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), MODEL_FILE)):
    print("Downloading model")
    opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
    opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
    for file in tar_file.getmembers():
        file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
        if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
            tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


# Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(
    label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# Helper code
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
        (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)



sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)


def dectect_func(location, id, model_name):
    VID_SAVE_PATH = '/tensorflow/downloads/'
    # Define the video stream
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(location)  # Change only if you have more than one webcams
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(VID_SAVE_PATH + id + '.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
    while True:
        # Read frame from camera
        ret, image_np = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        # Extract image tensor
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Extract detection boxes
        boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Extract detection scores
        scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        # Extract detection classes
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        # Extract number of detectionsd
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
            'num_detections:0')
        # Actual detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
            [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        '''
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)
        '''
        print(num_detections)

        # Display output
        cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            print("pressed q on window")
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()




# Detection
```

UPDATE 2 :

```
def process_video():

conn = sqlite3.connect(
    'db/abc.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(
    "SELECT id, location, model_name FROM uploads WHERE isProcessed=0 order by datetime DESC")

id, location, model_name = cur.fetchone()
print(id, location, model_name)
if not (id, location):
    cur.execute(
    "SELECT id, location FROM uploads WHERE isProcessed=0 order by datetime DESC")
func_name(location, id, model_name)

cur.execute("UPDATE uploads SET isProcessed=1  WHERE id='"+id+"'")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print('yes')
```

`update 3`

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
yes
File saved successfully
9da51fde-5deb-4f78-8f58-13661723daf8 uploads/output.mp4 ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17
/tensorflow/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17/frozen_inference_graph.pb
True
```

Here I output True on whether I am getting a frame or not, the last True is of the second file that I pass of which you can see the location and stuff. It takes only the first frame and the nothing happens.

Comment: Perhaps try not to create new session each time. Save it somewhere in the global variable, initialize graph outside the function as well. Let the only thing function is doing be `sess.run()`

Comment: Could you please share a small snippet maybe about what you said. From what I understand you mean that I initialize all the variables like image_tensor , boxes, scores that run inside the session as global variables and just do sess.run() in `with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:` is it so?  The standard object detection code i use is [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/camera.html) for reference.

Comment: I modified the code from the page you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some parts still remain those that you cannot enter into the debug call. 
UPDATE to this was a workaround of using `subprocess.run()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following modification works for me and lets to re-use detection loop:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)


def dectect_func(cap):
    while True:
        # Read frame from camera
        ret, image_np = cap.read()
        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        # Extract image tensor
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Extract detection boxes
        boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Extract detection scores
        scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        # Extract detection classes
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        # Extract number of detectionsd
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
            'num_detections:0')
        # Actual detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
            [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        '''
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)
        '''
        print(num_detections)

        # Display output
        cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            print("pressed q on window")
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break


dectect_func(cap)
dectect_func(cap)
```

I didn't clone tf `object_detection` repo, so here I go without visualization. But I see `num_detections` to change when I rotate camera.

EDIT: I think there is a problem with opencv saving files. Try this code:

```
def dectect_func(location, id):
    print('processing: ', location, id)
    VID_SAVE_PATH = 'out'
    # Define the video stream
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(location)  # Change only if you have more than one webcams
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(VID_SAVE_PATH + id + '.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480)) #cv2.VideoWriter(VID_SAVE_PATH + id + '.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
    while True:
        # Read frame from camera
        ret, image_np = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        # Extract image tensor
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Extract detection boxes
        boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Extract detection scores
        scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        # Extract detection classes
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        # Extract number of detectionsd
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
            'num_detections:0')
        # Actual detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
            [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.

        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)

        print(num_detections)

        # otherwise there will be no file saved if resolution mismatch
        frame = cv2.resize(image_np, (640,480), cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        out.write(frame)



    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



# Detection
dectect_func('small.mp4','0')
dectect_func('small.mp4','1')
```

Comment: Does this mean calling the `detect_func(cap)` twice?

Comment: @AshwinPhadke As far as I understand your question, you want to call detection second time to process another file. Here I wrote an example how the function can re-use session from global scope

Comment: @AshwinPhadke You can move all other tensors like `boxes`, `classes`, etc to the global scope as well to save computation. Then you can either take them from global scope, or pass then into function as perameters

Comment: Okay so I tried multiple versions of what you mentioned and it seems that it does wait for second time to process and enters the loop however it does not go past the first frame of the second video after  processing first, I am updating the entire code in the original question under `update 1`.

Comment: @AshwinPhadke More context is needed then to understand where the problem occurs. Can you somehow minimize your code to create reproducible example?

Comment: @AshwinPhadke check the edit. I resized output image to match exactly the size opencv wants, it's a known problem.

Comment: I added cv2.INTER_CUBIC part and kept both the resolutions same but that become the storing part. What not happening here is that the code executes `detect_func()` completely the first time but when I am trying to execute it the second time it doesn't even considering all the above changes, I guess it has to do with `tf.session()` and handling the loading of the graph and processing inputs. The above indeed has helped me solve many unseen issues.

Comment: @AshwinPhadke What exactly is happening when the function is called second time? What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message I even tried debugging, after it executes the first time it goes to the second function call get's the file and passes it to the detect_func() but now it reads the first frame of the file and basically freezes and nothing happens.

Comment: Added how the function gets called as Update 2.

Comment: @AshwinPhadke. Seems as possible opencv issue. Can you comment out `sess.run()` call and let opencv just to re-encode those video files?

Comment: Yes okay it looks like we are now going somewhere with this, so I commented the `sess.run()` call as you suggested and it is still the same error of getting only one frame of second video and then nothing. How do we tackle this?    
Added the trace in `update 3` as it was not being correct in the comment.

Comment: @AshwinPhadke It becomes hard to say when you cannot reproduce the error. You may try to check [`while cap.isOpened() status`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102833/python-opencv-cv2-videocapture-read-getting-stuck-indefinitely-after-running-t), also investigate whether this error occurs with any other file, or the second file is specific in some way (has different encoding). Does it freeze when the first good file is fed to the function second time?

Comment: @AshwinPhadke Do you close the first VideoCapture object properly? `cap.release()` and `out.release()` ?

Comment: @AshwinPhadke If you're not able to get opencv working, you may perhaps try [something else](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html) (didn't work with it, don't know)